# Reshaping/Grouping a 3D numpy array in a performant way

Tags: python, numpy, performance, reshape, nested-lists

I currently have a list of numpy arrays of shape (72(x), 4480(y),4(z)). What would be the most performant way to reshape or group these into something such as a hashmap where the Y would be unique and it would pull all of the Z's into each Y index while keeping the x index?

Thank you.

Comment: Will you please provide sample data (for random numbers, using `np.random.seed(0)` then `np.random.randint(low, high, (x, y, z))`) and expected output? I'm afraid this question will never be answered unless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reshape()` to transform your dimensions in numpy.

```
arr = np.repeat([1,2,3],430080).reshape(72,4480,4)
print(arr.shape)
print(arr.reshape(72,-1).shape)
(72, 4480, 4)
(72, 17920)
```